# Uninstall rEFInd and remove linux partition

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, refind

A couple years ago I added a Linux partition to my Mac laptop. I also installed rEFInd to manage my partitions. Now, I'd like to remove that partition, and uninstall rEFInd. However, Disk Utility does not seem to see the Linux partition. It sees the MacOS partition, and an unknown partition labelled "Linux Swap", which is only 4gb. I would like to remove my Linux partition and return that storage to the MacOS partition. In addition, I'd like to uninstall rEFInd. Does anyone know how this can be done?

If necessary, I have no problem wiping my drive completely and reinstalling MacOS. I've already made a backup of the files I'd like to keep, and made a USB which I can install MacOS from.

Thank you for any advice!

Edit:
Here's a dump from `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         210.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Linux Swap                         4.0 GB     disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         36.0 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +210.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            165.0 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 129.5 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.6 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a dump of your partition tables. You should be able to get it from either the `diskutil` or `gpt` command line tools.

Comment: @Spiff added it, thanks for the advice. It seems like maybe Disk Utility can't see the Linux partition because it's on "separate" disk? (disk1 is labeled synthesized)